# Запретить пользователю переходить в разделы в админке Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Есть две роли админ - имеет доступ ко всем настройкам админки,
контент менеджер - имеет доступ только к двум разделам админки

Я создал две роли admin и Content manager.
Контенту менеджеру дал пермишены на два раздела.

```
<?php

namespace console\controllers;

use common\models\User;
use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

    //CREATE CONTENT MANAGER ROLE
    $contentManagerRole = Yii::$app->authManager->createRole('content_manager');
    $contentManagerRole->description = 'Content manager';

    //CREATE ADMIN ROLE
    $adminRole = Yii::$app->authManager->createRole('admin');
    $adminRole->description = 'Administrator';
    $auth->add($adminRole);



    //COMPLAIN PERMISSIONS
    $indexComplain   = $auth->createPermission('complain-index');
    $viewComplain    = $auth->createPermission('complain-view');
    $createComplain  = $auth->createPermission('complain-create');
    $updateComplain  = $auth->createPermission('complain-update');
    $deleteComplain  = $auth->createPermission('complain-delete');

    //ANNOUNCEMENT PERMISSIONS
    $indexAnnouncement   = $auth->createPermission('announcement-index');
    $viewAnnouncement    = $auth->createPermission('announcement-view');
    $createAnnouncement  = $auth->createPermission('announcement-create');
    $updateAnnouncement  = $auth->createPermission('announcement-update');
    $deleteAnnouncement  = $auth->createPermission('announcement-delete');

    $auth->add($indexComplain);
    $auth->add($viewComplain);
    $auth->add($createComplain);
    $auth->add($updateComplain);
    $auth->add($deleteComplain);

    $auth->add($indexAnnouncement);
    $auth->add($viewAnnouncement);
    $auth->add($createAnnouncement);
    $auth->add($updateAnnouncement);
    $auth->add($deleteAnnouncement);


    $auth->add($contentManagerRole);


    //ADDING PERMISSIONS IN ROLE CONTENT MANAGER
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $indexComplain);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $viewComplain);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $createComplain);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $updateComplain);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $deleteComplain);


    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $indexAnnouncement);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $viewAnnouncement);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $createAnnouncement);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $updateAnnouncement);
    $auth->addChild($contentManagerRole, $deleteAnnouncement);


    $auth->addChild($adminRole, $contentManagerRole);



    $auth->assign($contentManagerRole, User::getContentManagerUser()->id);
    $auth->assign($adminRole, User::getAdminUser()->id);
  }
}
```

В конфиг положил ACF

```
    'as beforeRequest' => [
    'class' => 'yii\filters\AccessControl',
    'rules' => [

        //COMMON
        [
            'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['admin', 'content_manager'],
        ],

        //ADMIN
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['admin'],
        ],

        //CONTENT MANAGER
        [
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['content_manager'],
        ],

        [
            'actions' => ['login'],
            'allow' => true,
            'roles' => ['?']
        ],

    ],
],
```

Как мне написать правило, при котором контент менеджер может переходить в разделы на которые я дал пермишены, на остальные 403.

В контроллеры с 2-мя разделами добавил access такого вида

```
            'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'roles' => ['complain-index'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'roles' => ['complain-view'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['create'],
                    'roles' => ['complain-create'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['update'],
                    'roles' => ['complain-update'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['delete'],
                    'roles' => ['complain-delete'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему.
Создал базовый контроллер в backend, там расставил доступы .

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\service\Rbac;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

class AdminController extends Controller
{

    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['GET'],
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],

        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [

                //COMMON
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin', 'content_manager'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?']
                ],

                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['admin', 'content_manager'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}

public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
    ];
}


public function beforeAction($action)
{

    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $rbac = new Rbac();
        $rbac->checkPermissionsForContentManager();
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
}
```

Все остальные контроллеры наследовал от базового.

Rbac service

```
<?php

namespace common\models\service;

use Yii;
use common\models\User;
use yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException;

class Rbac
{

/**
 * Backend controller ids array
 * for Content Manager
 * @var array
 */
public $permissionsContentManager = [
    'auth',
    'admin',
    'announcement',
    'complain',
    'site'

];


/**
 * @param $username
 * @return bool
 */
public static function isUserAdmin($username)
{
    $user = User::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    if ($user) {
        return in_array($user->id, Yii::$app->authManager->getUserIdsByRole('admin'));
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * @param $username
 * @return bool
 */
public static function isUserContentManager($username)
{
    $user = User::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    if ($user) {
        return in_array($user->id, Yii::$app->authManager->getUserIdsByRole('content_manager'));
    }

    return false;
}


public function checkPermissionsForContentManager()
{
    if (self::isUserContentManager(Yii::$app->user->identity->username)) {
        if (!in_array(Yii::$app->controller->id, $this->permissionsContentManager))
        {
            throw new ForbiddenHttpException('У вас нет доступа к этой странице ...', 403);
        }
    }
}


}
```

Не уверен в правильности решения, поскольку этот код можно написать и без использования RBAC.